# linking two lists python

Tags: python, python-3.6

How can I link these two lists so when one list changes(the order)
the other list follows keeping with the same numbers

```
List2=[5,4,3,2,1]
List3=[2,4,6,8,10]
```

changing the order of list2 and expected output

```
List2=[1,2,3,4,5]
List3=[10,8,6,4,2]
```

but the list2 order will change every time but always needs to be changed back to 1-5

(Python 3.6)

Comment: These two lists are independent of each other aren't they? Changing one list should have no effect on the other list. How are you changing the order of `list2`?

Comment: hi, they are inputted and I know I would like to somehow link them if its possible?

Comment: Oh my mistake, I misread the question, thanks for explaining further. But maybe the already provided answer helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a small helper function to sort the two lists based on one of them.

```
def revert(a, b):
    a, b = map(list, zip(*sorted(zip(a, b), key=lambda x: x[0])))
    return a, b
```

Now, call this function as and when needed.

```
List2, List3 = revert(List2, List3)
```

Comment: hi i am just testing this thanks for the fast answer give me a couple m!

Comment: omg COLDSPEED you a legend thank you so much seems to work ill comment if starts to not work thank you!

Comment: Hi should be a quick fix but getting:     JudgeList1, ScoreList1 = revert(JudgeList1, ScoreList1)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'JudgeList1' referenced before assignment

Comment: @GraphicsLab The two lists must already exist for this to work. I hope that you have not changed the variable names in the function either?

Comment: i have changed the names but its working and they should already exist so ill go through and check mate

Comment: wait what variable names in function?

Comment: @GraphicsLab I'm referring to the names of the variables in `revert`. :-) The variable names should not be changed inside the function. Don't assume your function can see these variables. You should always work with local variables.

Comment: i haven't changed anything in the function all ive changed is the list names

Comment: According to this error, it seems `JudgeList1` did not exist before you passed it to the function. Do take a look at your code, it seems unrelated to this function :-)

Comment: thanks i sorted it i dunno what was wrong but it would work within the function took it out and it worked so cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
List2=[5,4,3,2,1]
List3=[2,4,6,8,10]
```

The "easier" way would be to make a dictionary of dict3 and use that after you remake list 2. Something like this:

```
# Pair the lists
List3 = dict(zip(List2,List3))

# Remake List2
List2 = sorted(List2)

# Remake List3 based on List2
List3 = [List3[key] for key in List2]

List3
```

Returns:

```
[10, 8, 6, 4, 2]
```

Comment: i dont think this is what im looking for sorry

Comment: @GraphicsLab Might be the case, but with dictionaries these tasks become trivial.